# Drag-&-drop and Dockbar menu is not working in Chrome using touch laptop / screen

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have been using `Liferay 6.2.1 CE GA2` and both issues are reproducible in Chrome (only). I have also verified that you will find both of the above issues been fixed on latest `Liferay 6.2.5 CE GA6`. I further drilled down and identified that these issue were primarily fixed in `Liferay 6.2.2 CE GA3`.

My problem is that I am unable to find relevant ticket(s) in which these issues were fixed, as I just require these fixes (can not upgrade). It would be thankful, if someone can point out the exact tickets.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: [***Cross Posted***](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/70290888)

Comment: "is not working" isn't a very well reproducible error description... Thanks for trying out GA6 - this would have been my first suggestion. As it's hard to reproduce (especially without a touch screen, as it seems to be related to this), a screen-recording might be a good idea.

Comment: @OlafKock, [***here***](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=!AN6WWlUvRle_Emo&cid=CAAD669062CF15FA&id=CAAD669062CF15FA!251&parId=root&o=OneUp) it is.

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Counter question, as you can't upgrade: What are you doing with security issues that have been fixed since that old release? Do you backport them yourself? That time might be better invested in an upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: Yes, we are using community version and fix issues by own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hell of research and code debugging, I have been able to resolve both of the issues.
Thought of sharing my findings here, as this might be helpful for others.

> 1. Unable to Drag-&-drop portlets:

**Fix:** Upgrading alloy zip (`\portal-web\third-party\alloy-2.0.0.zip`) to `2.0.0.37` or later resolves this issue. Since, this was the only minor upgrade of zip between `Liferay 6.2 GA2 - GA6`.

> 2 . Dockbar menus not clickable:

**Fix:** Resolved it with following custom javascript hack:

```
var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !isOpera;

/* Run code, if application is running on touch device with chrome */
if(isTouchDevice() && isChrome){
    var docbar_dropdowns = 
        document.querySelectorAll('li.admin-links, li.my-sites, li.user-avatar');

    /* Attach click event */
    if(docbar_dropdowns.length > 0){    
        for(var d = 0; d < docbar_dropdowns.length; d++){
            docbar_dropdowns[d].addEventListener("click", toggleMenu, false);
        }
    }

    /* Toggle menu on click */
    var elementId = null;
    function toggleMenu(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        if(elementId != null && elementId != this.id)
            hideMenu();

        elementId = this.id;

        if(this.children[1].style.display == "block"){
            this.classList.remove("open");
            this.children[1].style.display = "none";
        }else{
            this.classList.add("open");
            this.children[1].style.display = "block";
        }
    }

    /* Hide previously opened menu */
    function hideMenu(){
        for(var d = 0; d < docbar_dropdowns.length; d++){
            docbar_dropdowns[d].classList.remove("open");
            docbar_dropdowns[d].children[1].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

    document.body.addEventListener("click", hideMenu, false);
}

/* Detect touch device */
function isTouchDevice() {
    return (('ontouchstart' in window)
    || (navigator.MaxTouchPoints > 0)
    || (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0));
}
```

**NOTE:** In our environment, both issues were only reproducible in chrome on touch devices / using mouse on touch laptop.